# Alamofire call not working inside loop

Tags: swift, loops, youtube-api, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a loop that is meant to make 10 different calls to Youtube's API using Alamofire, each with a different videoID that I get from another function. The call however, doesn't seem to be made because I'm not getting results from the Success nor Failure options in the Alamofire switch.

Can somebody point out whats wrong?

```
func getRecom(completion: (result:String)->()) {
    let array = defaults.arrayForKey("recomQuery")
    for i in 0..<10  {
    let videoURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2C+snippet&id=\(array![i])&maxResults=10&key=\(apiKey)"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, videoURL).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            print("success") //THIS IS NOT BEING CALLED
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let videoTitle = json["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"].stringValue
                print("Title from network \(videoTitle)")
                let thumbPath = String(json["items"][0]["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"])
                print(i)
                let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: thumbPath)!)!)!
                let newImage: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
                self.recomTitles.append(videoTitle)
                self.recomThumbs.append(newImage)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("failure") //THIS IS ALSO NOT BEING CALLED
            print(error)
            completion(result: "done")
            }
        }
    }
print("saving array: \(defaults.arrayForKey("recomTitles"))")
defaults.setObject(recomThumbs, forKey: "recomThumbs")
defaults.setObject(recomTitles, forKey: "recomTitles")
completion(result: "done")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody! I figured it was an asynch call so that the completion was being called before time, I fixed it by adding inside the loop:

```
if i == 9 { completion(result: "done") } //9 being the last index of loop
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

***If*** you run this in Playground, the chances are that the program ends before the print is called, because you call it from an async method. If that's the case, call XCPExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely() at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out Alamofire was probably an asynch call and fixed it with my explanation above!